# how to get date by day number or day name in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-5

is there a built-in method that give me a date of the day by giving it the day name or number
ex: input: Saturday => output: 28-3-2020

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Date.parse('Saturday').strftime('%d-%-m-%Y')
#=> "28-3-2020"
```

From comments, may try this approach to get a week's data

```
date_by_day = Date.parse('Saturday')
#=> Sat, 28 Mar 2020

start_date = date_by_day - 7
#=> Sat, 21 Mar 2020

end_date = start_day + 6
#=> Fri, 27 Mar 2020
```

Hope that helps!

It will give you the date of next Saturday.

Comment: there is no way to get the current Saturday I tried to subtract 7adys but it will not be right in cases like Friday

Comment: @MuhammadElbadawy Can you show me what you are trying?

Comment: I'm trying to export a report about the current week even if I am at the start of the week or the middle.
USERNAME SAT SUN MON TUE WED THU FRI

Comment: @MuhammadElbadawy But your question doesn't mention any of that?

Comment: Because just what I need is to parse a day name of the current week and return its date so I can get the data regarding to the date

Comment: @MuhammadElbadawy The answer should return the same, in which case its not working?

Comment: like today is Tuesday and the report should export data about the current week by your way it will begin from next Saturday but I want the range to be from the last Saturday to Friday which will be tomorrow

Comment: @MuhammadElbadawy Just edited my answer, does it help?